# Error when attempting to unzip a corrupt zip file using a python script

Tags: python

I am trying to download and unzip Xray security violation reports using a python script. Some zip files are valid, but some zip files are corrupt and cannot be unzipped using the python script. I can extract these file using the command line but cannot do so using python. In the zip file's Properties -> archive tab, you can see that there are zero files.

Here is the error I get:

*Exception has occurred: ReadError
report.xray.zip is not a zip file*

This is the python unzip command I use. I tried many other commands and none worked:

`shutil.unpack_archive(pathtozip)`

Thanks

Comment: what other commands did you try?

Comment: I tried z = zipfile.ZipFile(file), z.extractall(folder). I used with gzip.open(file, 'rb') as f:, file_content = f.read(). with tarfile.open('somefile.zip', "r:gz") as f: f.extractall()